# Load 10 items at a time when scroll to bottom load more items on tableview ios ,swift , Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Loading all the date from the firebase to the tableview at a time but i wanted to load 10 items at a time when i scroll to bottom again 10 items should load to the tableview, below is my code

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inciCell") as! 
 IncidentCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.setupCell(with: item, indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In the delegate method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you may check something like `indexPath.row == items.count - 1`.
2. if it's true, then you get 10 items from your DB and `append` it to your `items.
3. then do `tableView.reloadData()` to update the table view with 10 new items.

You may also make some nice spinner in the bottom (`tableFooterView`) of the table view. But it could be the next step.

Hope it helps.